# O que está por trás da função de alocação dinâmica malloc()?

Tags: c, memória, alocação

Quais os mecanismos que a função `malloc()` utiliza na prática para gerenciar a alocação dinâmica de memória em um programa?

Comment: Link para [artigo bastante completo da IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-memory/), em ingles.

Comment: Não é bem duplicada, mas esta outra pergunta pode ser de ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-o-stack-e-heap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resumidamente:

O seu programa/processo ocupa uma região de memória que vai de um endereço `x` até um endereço `y` chamado de monte (*heap*). Todos seus `malloc`s são alocados nesta área entre `x` e `y`. Ele mantém uma estrutura de dados, digamos que uma lista, que contém todos os espaços livres da pilha deste processo.

Quando você chamar o `malloc`, ele olha através desta lista e procura um espaço que seja grande o suficiente para o tamanho que você deseja alocar. Se possui este tamanho disponível, ele retorna um ponteiro para este espaço, registra que irá usá-lo e a partir dai o seu programa irá usar aquela fatia na memória.

Quando você desaloca chamando o `free()`, ele pega esse espaço utilzado que agora será liberado, desregistra ele e agora esse espaço liberado vai para a lista e caso ocorra algum novo pedido de alocação, tem-se espaço disponível novamente.

Se você chamar `malloc()` e ele não conseguir encontrar qualquer espaço grande o suficiente na pilha, ele usa o *syscall* `brk()` para aumentar essa faixa. Ou seja, aumentar endereço `y` e realocar todos os endereços antigos e o novo `y` para ser uma faixa de memória válida.

`brk()` é uma *syscall*, e portanto não há nenhuma maneira de fazer a mesma coisa na camada de usuário.

Procure mais informações sobre a *syscall* se desejar entender o funcionamento da *syscall* em si.

Comment: Só atento que a tradução de *heap* seria monte, e não pilha. Pilha é *stack*. Já editei a sua resposta para arrumar isso.